# How to modify variable inside promise in typescript (scope and 'this' issue)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have set up a project in ionic 4.5.0 using typescript 2.2.1.

In it, I have two classes

```
file functions.ts
/* lots of import */
@Injectable()
export class Functions {
  language: string;
}

file fooclass.ts
/* lots of import and import of functions.ts */
export class FooClass {
   constructor(public functions: Functions) {
     this.functions.language="ENG";
   }

   somefunction() {
     console.log("1 - language: "+this.functions.language);
     this.someotherfunction().then((response) => {
        console.log("2 - language: "+this.functions.language);
     })
     console.log("3 - language: "+this.functions.language);
   }

someotherfunction() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     this.functions.language="ITA";
     resolve("done");   
  }
}
```

This prints out

```
1 - language: ENG
2 - language: ITA
3 - language: ENG
```

I though that using the fat arrow could bind the 'this' ambient so that making changes to the variable 'language' of this.functions could survive the promise someotherfunction but it seems not. How could I modify the variable language and make the change survive outside the promise?

EDIT: I realized now that the issue came after an upgrade from a previous version of ionic. Maybe it shouldn't behave like this and it's some sot of bug? (I have a previous version of the software and that is working, with the same code)

Comment: Doesn't it print in order 1,3,2??

Comment: maybe but it is not a matter of 'time' and asynchronicity. This is an example. In the real code, later on, when I am sure the modification of the variable has been done, i try to use this.functions.language obtaining the previuos value

Comment: I suspect your example doesn't match your real code closely enough for us to answer your question. In your example, you set `this.functions.language` in FooClass's `constructor`, but you never set `this.functions` to begin with (and you never do anything with your `functions` argument), so in actual use this code would throw a TypeError. Please edit your question to include code that we can actually run in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It looks like `functions` might be shared by multiple classes or instances. Setting `language` in one would change the value for all of the shared references. Is it possible that some code elsewhere changes the code back to `"ENG"`? Maybe the initialization code that sets the default language runs again after your promise resolves?

Comment: It's difficult to produce code that can be actually reproduced in a fiddle for the ionic framework structure is a bit complicate unfortunately. I've made a lot of test and the behaviour is really strange. I hope to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

There may be some issue with how you're using `functions` in the constructor.  This works:

```js
class FooClass {
  constructor() {
    this.language="ENG";
  }

  somefunction() {
    console.log("1 - language:" + this.language);
    this.someotherfunction()
    .then((response)=>{
      console.log("2 - language: " + this.language);
    });
    console.log("3 - language: " + this.language);
  }

  someotherfunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
      this.language = "ITA";
      resolve("done");   
    });
  }
}

const foo = new FooClass();
foo.somefunction();
```

When saving the functions parameter, it also works:

```js
class FooClass {
  constructor(functions) {
    this.functions = functions;
  }

  somefunction() {
    console.log("1 - language:" + this.functions.language);
    this.someotherfunction()
    .then((response)=>{
      console.log("2 - language: " + this.functions.language);
    });
    console.log("3 - language: " + this.functions.language);
  }

  someotherfunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
      this.functions.language = "ITA";
      resolve("done");   
    });
  }
}

const foo = new FooClass({ language: "ENG"});
foo.somefunction();
```

Comment: maybe, but that's not the way the ionic framework handles things